# How do I remove the double quotes from a csv file using R before applying read.csv()?

Tags: r

I have a csv file in which some columns have double quotes in them. I want to remove all these double quotes in R before I apply read.csv() on this file to store the data in a data frame.

Comment: Why not using the `quote` argument of `read.csv`? Or just use your favorite spreadsheet editor.

Comment: Why? I only ask this because to do what you ask "in R" you will have to `read` the `csv` in some way. Options include using `readLines`, but let's establish *Why* first.

Comment: I can manually clean it in Notepad++ using Cntrl+F but then I won't be able to automate this process by running of a script. 
I may be interested in refreshing this data periodically.

Comment: What do you mean by "double-quotes"? Like this ? `'"hello","this","is","quoted"'`.  You should never need to manually change the file to read it.  Try `read.table` as well

Comment: Yes. A file like that. Can you please post how I would resolve that using read.table? Please post as an answer.

Comment: What's the problem with `dat <- read.csv("file.csv")`?

Comment: The problem with read.csv("file.csv") is that it rejects those records which have double quotes in them. As a result, I end up getting a data frame of lesser rows.

Comment: Could you give us a few lines of the raw text file please

Answer (score 1):

```
 f <- "path/to/file.csv"
 raw <- readLines(f)
 raw <- gsub("\\\"\\\"", "\"", raw)
 DAT <- read.table(text=raw)
```

*updated to reflect Hugh's clarification below*

Comment: @hugh, we want to search for `\"`, however, we need escape both the quote character and the escape character, so that yields `\\ \"` or `\\\"`  we then want two of those ... `\\\"\\\"`   And the whole thing is one string, so we need to wrap it in quotes `"\\\"\\\""` -- thats what we are searching for.  We then replace it with the simpler single quote, which needs one escape charater

Comment: Sure, but I don't see how it contributes to `DAT`. Did you mean `raw <- gsub("\\\"\\\"", "\"", raw)`?

Comment: @hugh oh indeed!!  That was a sloppy ommition. Thanks for the catch!